# I want to learn how much distance take the function of setDistanceThreshold(). what is the metric of DistanceThreshold on point cloud library?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, pcl

I am trying to fit circle from point clouds and I used RandomSampleConsensus object on pcl.
I want to learn how much distance threshold calculated by the function of setDistanceThreshold(double threshold) such as cm,mm,or meter?
`ransac.setDistanceThreshold(0.01);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking about the unit of the parameter `threshold`? That depends entirely on the unit of the cloud you are using.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the unit of the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge it is dependent on your input. I have point clouds where x, y, and z are stored in mm. `setDistanceThreshold(1)` would than be 1mm threshold. A point cloud storing coordinates in m would result in a 1m threshold.